# Rendering UIImage in CGContext doesn't show image's shadow

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, core-image, cgcontext

I'm trying to get an image from a UIImageView including it's layer properties (shadow and border); however I'm not seeing the shadow in the resulting image. The above image is my "imageView" and below is the "previewImageView." Notice the shadow is missing in the previewImageView, but the border is there.

Here's my code:

```
func convertButtonAction() {
    let img = imageFromLayer(layer: imageView.layer)
    previewImageView.image = img
}

func imageFromLayer(layer: CALayer) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, 0)
    layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return outputImage!
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create context with layer frame size but shadow is outside of bounds. Try increase `layer.frame.size` in `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

Add a new UIView and make it the parent of your UIImageView, and give it enough inset to hold the UIImageView's shadow.

Then use [UIView.drawHierarchy()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622589-drawhierarchy) to render the new view (and the child imageview) to your private bitmap context.